# How to globally enable --no-verify-ssl in aws cli, and also how to disable that?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am getting a SSL validation failure, while my Python code is trying to interact with S3 bucket. The error further says

> unable to get local issuer certificate. (_ssl.c:1131)

That issue will eventually get fixed in the legit way.

But, for now, I need a quick fix. Many answers mention about the risks of using `--no-verify-ssl`, but no one tells how to use it.

Is it possible to enable that globally? Also, can I disable it, when the issue is fixed in the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `--no-verify-ssl`. Doing so opens yourself up to man-in-the-middle attacks and ignores your obligations under the shared responsibility model.

If you don't have the CAs installed in your environment's trust store, you can manually pass the CA bundle using the `--ca-bundle` option or the `ca_bundle` config key.

### Example Usage

1. Create the AWS CA Bundle

```bash
 curl https://www.amazontrust.com/repository/{SFSRootCAG2,AmazonRootCA4,AmazonRootCA3,AmazonRootCA2,AmazonRootCA1}.pem >> ~/.aws/ca_bundle.pem
```

2. Configure the SDK (choice)

   - Add it to the [config file](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#:%7E:text=for%20backward%20compatibility.-,ca_bundle,-The%20CA%20bundle) at `~/.aws/config`. If you have the CLI installed it should exist and can be set with a command: `aws configure set ca_bundle '~/.aws/ca_bundle.pem'`
   - Pass it as an [environment variable](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#:%7E:text=%7E/.boto.-,AWS_CA_BUNDLE,-The%20path%20to): `AWS_CA_BUNDLE='~/.aws/ca_bundle.pem'`
     https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/index.html
     https://www.amazontrust.com/repository/

Comment: Okay, I won't use that. Just tell me how to use it. Some steps like: open cmd > type --no-verify-ssl .. not recognized.

Comment: @layman I've added some steps you can follow.

Comment: Note that if SSL inspection is breaking the AWS CLI connections (the reason for using `--no-verify-ssl` to begin with), then the command to fetch the CAs will often break also, with `curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: Unknown error (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.`  The workaround is to pass `--ssl-no-revoke` to curl to skip checking for CRLs on that connection -- and if that's not allowed, then the SSL inspection is too intrusive to be useful.